# Display the sort order of a SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, simplecursoradapter

I've implemented a ListFragment with a SimpleCursor. When I query the full list I sort by one of the fields. Works great. What I want to do is go back through the sorted list and populate a TextView in the row with the ordinal value. Basically, I wanted a sorted list numbered 1, 2, etc. I'm letting the SimpleCursor do the sort, which seems like a good idea, but I have no idea how to get the sort order and display it. I tried the following to no avail.

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    TextView tv;
    ListView lv = (ListView)getListView();
    for(int i = 0; i < lv.getChildCount(); i++) {
          View v = (View)lv.getChildAt(i);
          tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.rank);
          if (tv != null) {
              tv.setText(Integer.toString(i+1));
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: **"I tried the following to no avail."** What does that mean exactly? What actually happens when you try that code? I suspect the problem is with using the `getChildCount()` method of `ListView` - this is not the same as the actual number of data records referenced by a `Cursor` - it's the number of list items visible on the screen.

Comment: I meant that it didn't update the display of the ListView.

Comment: You should probably extend `SimpleCursorAdapter` and override the `getView(...)` method. There are plenty of examples of doing this on StackOverflow or check the Android developers doc site.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It turns out I was binding that text field to the cursor. Once I disassociated it, it worked.